# how can I make a detailed data.table neater?

Tags: r, data.table

Please find the toy sample.

```
> pkg.installed <- as.data.table(installed.packages())
> pkg.installed
*          Package                                           LibPath  Version    Priority
* 1:    data.table        C:/Users/eric1/Documents/R/win-library/4.0   1.12.8        <NA>
* 2:          here        C:/Users/eric1/Documents/R/win-library/4.0      0.1        <NA>
* 3:     rprojroot        C:/Users/eric1/Documents/R/win-library/4.0    1.3-2        <NA>
* 4:          base C:/Program Files/Microsoft/R Open/R-4.0.2/library    4.0.2        base
*                                                                   Depends                                          Imports LinkingTo
* 1:                                                           R (>= 3.1.0)                                          methods      <NA>
* 2:                                                                   <NA>                               rprojroot (>= 1.2)      <NA>
* 3:                                                           R (>= 3.0.0)                                        backports      <NA>
* 4:                                                                   <NA>                                             <NA>      <NA>
*                                                                   Depends                                          Imports LinkingTo
*                                                                                             Suggests                              Enhances
* 1:                                             bit64, curl, R.utils, knitr, xts, nanotime, zoo, yaml                                  <NA>
* 2:                                                                                              <NA>                                  <NA>
* 3:                                                          testthat, mockr, knitr, withr, rmarkdown                                  <NA>
* 4:                                                                                           methods                                  <NA>
```

As you can see, it might takes few more keystokes to see all the table, and still feel confused.
I am a 110% data.table fan, yet still wondering how I can make the table in a neater way of seeing, after all, sometimes we are more focusing on the columns, rather than the cell contents.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: How do wish to see, "neater" is not clear enough, what is the expected output?

Comment: `DT::datatable(pkg.installed)`?

Comment: Relevant GitHub peep package, that hides middle columns to fit into console size - https://github.com/romunov/peep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is open FR for some improvements in printing. You can subscribe to it if you want to get update on that matter: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1374

What you can do as of now

```r
d = as.data.table(installed.packages())
options(datatable.prettyprint.char=15)
print(d, trunc.cols=TRUE)
```